# rEFIt boot changed after update to Yosemite

Tags: mac, macos, startup, efi

I was using rEFIt to work with Ubuntu with my Mac. After the upgrade to Yosemite I had a problem with rEFIt. I found the following solution on [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2236552) but rEFIt still didn't work:

```
cd /efi/refit
./enable.sh
```

So I tried to install rEFInd. It "works", or better, at the boot of the Mac I can see the Linux and Apple partition, but if I choose the linux one it doesn't work. The message "No Bootable Device" appears on screen.

I think that the problem is that the Yosemite update has changed the rEFIt table. Indeed, now I have 2 recovery partitions when, before the update, I only had one.

This is what `diskutil list` shows:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh SSD           231.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4
   5: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               23.2 GB    disk0s5
```

Obviously the corrupted partition is the last one.

I have important information in my Ubuntu partition which I do not wish to lose.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you able to access that Linux partition at all anymore? You say it's "corrupted" but I don't even see it in the list at all.

Comment: @user15877 i can't access to that partition. I could use a live-usb ubuntu and then i mounted the partition. So if i want i can copy my files in an external device. The problem still that i need to recovery the partition because the file that i have inside are important but more important is all the environment that my friend installed, and that i'm absolutely not able to do.

Comment: @grgarside i have changed the terminal output image in text.